# How to synchronize a folder localy between Android and Windows

Tags: android, windows, synchronization, directory, share

My question is pretty simple but I do not find a detailed answer. I'm working on an app which need to get files from a Windows directory. I try everything I found on the internet but it seems to be impossible. I do not want to pass through a web service as all I need is :

- Open my app (check)
- Click on a button to open a ListView (check)
- Fill this view with my information get from my pc (non-check)
- Download one file from the list (non-check)
- Open the file (check when I saved it on my sd card)

The thing is, the user do not have the access on Windows so he can't send those files (A software is running on the pc, disabling the user access on Windows and this same software save data on a directory, the one that in need to get), but me, the developer, I can install thing on the OS.

If anybody find any easy way to refresh an Android directory with files from a directory on windows, it will be realy usefull. Moreover, i'm not the only one who looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

PC: a FTP server

android: a FTP client

when you open a file on your app . app should download file from pc through FTP or upload ...

Comment: Ok! Any clue on how to acheive this?